# Can men wear jewelry?

Tags: halal-haram, men, clothing

Back then men used to wear jewelry and even skirts (things that are seen as female-associated now), but aren't these things just social gender norms that people themselves have created over time?

So I'm not certain as to how a man wearing jewelry or something could cause anyone harm or make them any less a Muslim.

Comment: It **would** make you less of a muslim because you would be disobeying the Prophet: https://sunnah.com/urn/1278420

Comment: An important clarification would be what constitute a jewelry as per Islam. From Hadiths we know that the Prophet (SAW) wore rings. But in modern day rings are also considered jewelry.